# Why does Haskell's `head` crash on an empty list (or why *doesn't* it return an empty list)? (Language philosophy)

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, parametric-polymorphism

Note to other potential contributors: Please don't hesitate to use abstract or mathematical notations to make your point. If I find your answer unclear, I will ask for elucidation, but otherwise feel free to express yourself in a comfortable fashion.

To be clear: I am *not* looking for a "safe" `head`, nor is the choice of `head` in particular exceptionally meaningful. The meat of the question follows the discussion of `head` and `head'`, which serve to provide context.

I've been hacking away with Haskell for a few months now (to the point that it has become my main language), but I am admittedly not well-informed about some of the more advanced concepts nor the details of the language's philosophy (though I am more than willing to learn). My question then is not so much a technical one (unless it is and I just don't realize it) as it is one of philosophy.

For this example, I am speaking of `head`.

As I imagine you'll know,

```
Prelude> head []    
*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list
```

This follows from `head :: [a] -> a`. Fair enough. Obviously one cannot return an element of (hand-wavingly) no type. But at the same time, it is simple (if not trivial) to define

```
head' :: [a] -> Maybe a
head' []     = Nothing
head' (x:xs) = Just x
```

I've seen some little discussion of this [here](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/functional-programming.html) in the comment section of certain statements. Notably, one Alex Stangl says

> 'There are good reasons not to make everything "safe" and to throw exceptions when preconditions are violated.'

I do not necessarily question this assertion, but I am curious as to what these "good reasons" are.

Additionally, a Paul Johnson says,

> 'For instance you could define "safeHead :: [a] -> Maybe a", but now instead of either handling an empty list or proving it can't happen, you have to handle "Nothing" or prove it can't happen.'

The tone that I read from that comment suggests that this is a notable increase in difficulty/complexity/something, but I am not sure that I grasp what he's putting out there.

One Steven Pruzina says (in 2011, no less),

> "There's a deeper reason why e.g 'head' can't be crash-proof. To be polymorphic yet handle an empty list, 'head' must always return a variable of the type which is absent from any particular empty list. It would be Delphic if Haskell could do that...".

Is polymorphism lost by allowing empty list handling? If so, how so, and why? Are there particular cases which would make this obvious? **This section amply answered by @Russell O'Connor.** Any further thoughts are, of course, appreciated.

I'll edit this as clarity and suggestion dictates. Any thoughts, papers, etc., you can provide will be most appreciated.

Comment: Neither is 'head' unsafe (it is partial, it is not total) nor does it throw an exception (it is undefined for an empty list).

Answer (score 107, accepted):

> Is polymorphism lost by allowing empty
>   list handling? If so, how so, and why?
>   Are there particular cases which would
>   make this obvious?

The free theorem for `head` states that

```
f . head = head . $map f
```

Applying this theorem to `[]` implies that

```
f (head []) = head (map f []) = head []
```

This theorem must hold for every `f`, so in particular it must hold for `const True` and `const False`.  This implies

```
True = const True (head []) = head [] = const False (head []) = False
```

Thus if `head` is properly polymorphic and `head []` were a total value, then `True` would equal `False`.

PS. I have some other comments about the background to your question to the effect of if you have a precondition that your list is non-empty then you should enforce it by using a non-empty list type in your function signature instead of using a list.

Comment: That is just the sort of answer I was looking for. I'm looking forward to your other comments, if you care to make them. :)

Comment: And I've just looked up Wadler's _Theorems for Free!_ for some more reading on the subject of free theorems.

Comment: I don't see why this causes problems with `head :: [a] -> Maybe a`, which has a free theorem `fmap f . head = head . map f` and thus you just get `Nothing == Nothing`. Unless you're just trying to show why it's impossible to have a `default :: forall a . a` value which could be returned for `head []` and that we could pattern match on... but there are simpler ways to talk about that.

Comment: @J.Abrahamson c.f. Data.List.Safe

Answer (score 27):

Why does anyone use `head :: [a] -> a` instead of pattern matching?  One of the reasons is because you know that the argument cannot be empty and do not want to write the code to handle the case where the argument is empty.

Of course, your `head'` of type `[a] -> Maybe a` is defined in the standard library as [`Data.Maybe.listToMaybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Maybe.html#v:listToMaybe).  But if you replace a use of `head` with `listToMaybe`, you have to write the code to handle the empty case, which defeats this purpose of using `head`.

I am not saying that using `head` is a good style.  It hides the fact that it can result in an exception, and in this sense it is not good.  But it is sometimes convenient.  The point is that `head` serves some purposes which cannot be served by `listToMaybe`.

The last quotation in the question (about polymorphism) simply means that it is impossible to define a function of type `[a] -> a` which returns a value on the empty list (as Russell O'Connor explained in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364409/why-does-haskells-head-crash-on-an-empty-list-or-why-doesnt-it-return-an-e/6364990#6364990)).

Answer (score 8):

It's only natural to expect the following to hold: `xs === head xs : tail xs` - a list is identical to its first element, followed by the rest. Seems logical, right?

Now, let's count the number of conses (applications of `:`), disregarding the actual elements, when applying the purported 'law' to `[]`: `[]` should be identical to `foo : bar`, but the former has 0 conses, while the latter has (at least) one. Uh oh, something's not right here!

Haskell's type system, for all its strengths, is not up to expressing the fact that you should only call `head` on a non-empty list (and that the 'law' is only valid for non-empty lists). Using `head` shifts the burden of proof to the programmer, who should make sure it's not used on empty lists. I believe dependently typed languages like Agda can help here.

Finally, a slightly more operational-philosophical description: how should `head ([] :: [a]) :: a` be implemented? Conjuring a value of type `a` out of thin air is impossible (think of uninhabited types such as `data Falsum`), and would amount to proving anything (via the Curry-Howard isomorphism).

Comment: "would amount to proving anything (via the Curry-Howard isomorphism)"

That's a very interesting point. I hadn't considered such a connection. Well put.

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of different ways to think about this.  So I am going to argue both for and against `head'`:

Against `head'`:

There is no need to have `head'`:  Since lists are a concrete data type, everything that you can do with `head'` you can do by pattern matching.

Furthermore, with `head'` you're just trading off one functor for another.  At some point you want to get down to brass tacks and get some work done on the underlying list element.

In defense of `head'`:

But pattern matching obscures what's going on.  In Haskell we are interested in calculating functions, which is better accomplished by writing them in point-free style using compositions and combinators.

Furthermore, thinking about the `[]` and `Maybe` functors, `head'` allows you to move back and forth between them (In particular the `Applicative` instance of `[]` with `pure = replicate`.)

Comment: Though, by some logic that suggests that there is no need to have `head` at all, yet it remains.

Overall, I rather like your answer, and I'd be interested in any other thoughts you have on the points you've made.

Comment: Practically speaking, there are times where I want `head` and others where I wished I had (or I just define) `head'`.

Comment: @MtnViewMark If you are wishing for `head'`, you need look no further than `Data.Maybe.listToMaybe`.

Comment: Maybe `head'' :: MonadPlus m => [a] -> m a` would be even more useful.

Answer (score 3):

If in your use case an empty list makes no sense at all, you can always opt to use [`NonEmpty`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/NonEmptyList/0.0.9/doc/html/Data-List-NonEmpty.html) instead, where `neHead` is safe to use. If you see it from that angle, it's not the `head` function that is unsafe, it's the whole list data-structure (again, for that use case).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a matter of simplicity and beauty. Which is, of course, in the eye of the beholder.

If coming from a Lisp background, you may be aware that lists are built of cons cells, each cell having a data element and a pointer to next cell. The empty list is not a list per se, but a special symbol. And Haskell goes with this reasoning.

In my view, it is both cleaner, simpler to reason about, and more traditional, if empty list and list are two different things.

...I may add - if you are worried about head being unsafe - don't use it, use pattern matching instead:

```
sum     [] = 0
sum (x:xs) = x + sum xs
```

Comment: Oh, certainly, I always prefer pattern matching to `head`. This is more a curiosity than a concern.

Re the rest of your comment: Traditional in what sense? Whose tradition? Why is it the tradition?

Comment: Well, the tradition of functional programming. I may have to eat up my own words instantly - in Lisp, (car '()) returns NIL. But Haskell was more an attempt to unify the modern functional programming crowd. And both OCaml and Miranda (I believe) give an error on doing head on empty list.

Comment: And it is that historical curiosity that I am trying to rationalize. Roughly (_extremely_ roughly), `[]` is equivalent to the empty set. In the mathematical context, the empty set is simply _the_ set with nothing in it. Similarly, `[]` is still a list, and should in fact be _the_ list with no elements (and possibly no type). If this is (for instance) a limitation of the typed lambda calculus, that could help explain the treatment of `[]`, but I am not sure this is the case.