# Why is init a partial function?

Tags: haskell

According to the [Haskell 2010 report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch9.html#x16-1720009.1), `init` is defined as the following:

```
init             :: [a] -> [a]  
init [x]         =  []  
init (x:xs)      =  x : init xs  
init []          =  error "Prelude.init: empty list"
```

[base-4.4.1.0](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.4.1.0) defines it similarly. To me, it seems that it would be perfectly acceptable and intuitive to have:

```
init [] = []
```

which would make `init` a total function. Since this definition made it into the haskell 2010 report I guess that there are arguments for it. Is that the case or is it defined that way because of tradition and backwards compatibility?

Comment: init should return all but the last element of a list. Empty lists don't have a last element, so no init as well. Plus, the invariant `xs == init xs ++ [last xs]` would no longer hold if init were defined in the way you describe.

Comment: @Niklas But, similarly you could say, init should return all the elements that are not the last element, there are no such elements so we should return the empty list.

Comment: @Niklas, wouldn't it still hold? I mean if last [] = []

Comment: @Magnus: No, as `last` wouldn't have a defined type then. Plus, `[] ++ [[]] != []`. Maybe you confused `last` with `tail`?

Comment: @Niklas , if `init [] == []` , `init xs ++ [last xs]` is still undefined when `xs == []` since `last` is not defined for `[]`, so I guess Magnus Kronqvist has a point...

Comment: @HaskellElephant: You are right, I din't think of that. But as Landei pointed out, it would still break the invariant `length (init xs) - 1 == length xs`

Comment: @Niklas I think you mean ` + 1`, and the problem I have with these invariants relying on init beeing undefined for `[]` is that they implicitly assert that `xs /= []` or else the whole expression is undefined, but those points are still valid, I just don't get why that is nice.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The same reason `tail []` isn't `[]`; it breaks the invariants that *define* these functions. We can define `head` and `tail` by saying that if `head` and `tail` are defined for a value `xs`, then `xs ≡ head xs : tail xs`.

As Niklas pointed out, the invariant we want to define `init` and `last` is `xs ≡ init xs ++ [last xs]`. It's true that `last` isn't defined on empty lists either, but why should `last` be defined if `init` can't be? Just like it would be wrong if one of `head` or `tail` was defined on an input while the other wasn't, `init` and `last` are two sides of the same coin, splitting a list into two values that together are equivalent to the original.

For a more "practical" view (although being able to reason about programs in terms of useful invariants about the operations they use has *very* practical benefit!), an algorithm that uses `init` will probably not behave correctly on an empty list, and  if `init` worked that way, it would work to hide the errors produced. It's better for `init` to be conservative about its inputs so that consideration has to be given for edge-cases like empty list when it is used, especially when it isn't at all clear that the proposed value for it to return in those cases is reasonable.

Here's a [previous Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364409/why-does-haskells-head-crash-on-an-empty-list-or-why-doesnt-it-return-an) about `head` and `tail`, including why `tail []` doesn't just return `[]`; the answers there should help to explain why these invariants are so important.

Comment: I think you meant "why should `init` be defined when `last` can't be?".

Answer (score 11):

Because I find the question interesting, I decided to write down my thoughts on the subject:

**Logical**

Say we define `init xs` as "the list, that, if you put `last xs` on its end, is equal to **xs**. This is equivalent to: `init xs` is the list without its last element. For `xs == []`, there exists no last element, so `init []` has to be undefined.

You could add a special case for this, like in "if **xs** is the empty list, then `init xs` is the empty list, otherwise `init xs` is the list, that, if you put `last xs` on its end, is equal to **xs**". Notice how this is much more verbose and less clean. We introduce additional complexity, but what for?

**Intuitive**

```
init [1,2,3,4] == [1,2,3]
init [1,2,3]   == [1,2]
init [1,2]     == [1]
init [1]       == []
init []        == ??
```

Note how the length of the lists on the right-hand side of the equations decreases along with the length of the left-hand side. To me, this series cannot be continued in a sensible way, because the list on the right side would have to have a negative size!

**Practical**

As others have pointed out, defining a special case handling for `init` or `tail` for the empty list as an argument, can introduce hard-to-spot errors in situations where functions can have no sensible result for the empty list, but still don't produce an exception for it!

Furthermore, I can think of no algorithm were it would actually be of advantage to have `init []` evaluate to `[]`, so why introduce that extra complexity? Programming is all about simplicity and especially Haskell is all about purity, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: There is one obvious and sensible continuation of your intuitive series, and that is to recognize that an explicitly undefined case needs to be represented as such. The correct type for `init` is thus `[a] -> Maybe [a]`, with `init [] = Nothing`.

Comment: Yeah, but that would mean that we need to handle the special case whenever we call `init` (e.g. by wrapping every call into a `fromJust`)... I don't like this very much.

Comment: What? No, `fromJust` is an absolutely terrible function and shouldn't exist at all. The correct thing to do is handle every case and not write partial functions in the first place.

Comment: @C.A.McCann: I absolutely agree that `fromJust` is darn ugly. However, I have never tried to avoid every single partial function, always thought it would just blow up the code unnecessarily. Maybe this is because I come from an imperative background :P

Comment: It doesn't bloat the code that much. For one thing, if a function isn't defined on some arguments it might just have the wrong type signature. If the argument types only include the values you want, the code won't be any bigger than otherwise. When that's not possible, you can use the `Monad` instances for `Maybe` and `Either` to let errors automatically propagate upward, much like exceptions in other languages.

Comment: @C.A.McCann: This is very interesting. What about defining `init` only on [NonEmpty](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/NonEmptyList/0.0.9/doc/html/Data-List-NonEmpty.html) lists? Wouldn't it be a cleaner way to exclude the special case instead of "accepting" it and returning some error indicator?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant about the argument types including only the values you want. It's not a universal solution, though, because the new type for `init` would be `NonEmpty a -> [a]`, so we're still adding one case to the output--a non-empty list becomes a list that might or might not be empty.

Answer (score 8):

The real issue here is that `init`, as defined, can't possibly work; it's an inherently partial function, just like `head` and `tail`. I'm not thrilled about how many deliberately partial functions exist in the standard libraries, but that's another matter.

Since `init` as given cannot be salvaged, we have two options:

- Take the interpretation that it's a filter on the given list, keeping all elements which are not the last element, and abandoning the invariants with respect to `length` and `last`. This can be written as `reverse . drop 1 . reverse`, which suggests an obvious generalization. We could introduce a similar counterpart for `take` if desired, as well.
- Recognize that `init` defines a partial function, and give it the correct type, `[a] -> Maybe [a]`. The error can then be correctly replaced with `Nothing`.

Comment: An obvious generalisation like `inits` :)

Comment: @ehird , well `inits` is more in line with `init [] = []` since  `inits [] == [[]]`. In a way its saying that the only init of [] is [], if it where to stick with `init [] = undefined`, it should be `inits [] == []`.

Comment: Hmm, I don't agree. `length (inits xs) ≡ length xs + 1`, so `length (inits []) ≡ 1`, and the only element it can possibly have is `[]`.

Comment: Another way to explain the behaviour of `inits` is that it starts with the empty list, and adds more elements until there aren't any left. I suppose that aligns fairly well with your definition of `init` as "every element that isn't the last".

Comment: @ehird: Actually, the generalization I had in mind was something equivalent to `\n -> reverse . drop n . reverse`, but `inits` is a good example as well.

Comment: @C.A.McCann: Right. I think I prefer `inits`, since it can be related to that version easily, and doesn't explicitly use "indices" (not really indices in this case, but still) into lists, which tend to be a bad sign IMO. But both seem useful. (I think my favourite replacement would be `end :: [a] -> Maybe ([a], a)`, since `init` is already doing the work you need for `last` too, and they often come in pairs; plus it doesn't throw any information away, which is nice.)

Answer (score 5):

It would be terrible to have `init [] = []`, especially it would break important invariants like `xs == init xs ++ [last xs]` and `length xs == 1 + length (init xs)`, and hence hide errors.

Answer (score 1):

It's traditional. At the time, they made an arbitrary choice, and now people are used to it.

They made `init` similar to `last`, so that they both fail on empty lists. (`tail` and `head` are another pair like that.)

But they could have chosen the opposite, as you suggest. Prelude could easily contain a function `tail' = drop 1`, as well as a matching `init'` function, allowing empty lists. I don't think this would be any problem—I'm unconvinced by all the talk of invariants and free theorems. It would just mean `init'` was a little dissimilar to its companion `last`; that's all.

(`last` and `head` are another story: Their signature is `[a] -> a`, so they must give back an element, and they can't make one out of thin air. In contrast, the type of `init` and `tail` is of course `[a] -> [a]`, which means they can and do yield empty lists.)